# How to remove action view from android menu item?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I added a progress-bar on menu using 
`menuItem.setActionView(new ProgressBar(getActivity()))`
when tapping on menu item.And after completing my operation I want to remove that progress.I tried with
`menuItem.SetActionView(null)`
But it didn't worked!

Answer (score 2):

It was my mistake.'menuItem.SetActionView(null)' will work perfectly.